# Vuetify: defining a base color for all text

Tags: css, vue.js, colors, themes, vuetify.js

I need to define a base color for **all** text in a Vue + Vuetify project. I've tried modifying the theme's primary color on vuetify.ts:

```
export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: "#E53935",
      },
    },
  },
})
```

This, however, only applies for some cases; v-text-input labels and text outside of Vuetify components, among others, won't use this value. Is there any good alternative to explicitly styling it via css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the variables using css. you need to configure the webpack.config.js as below.

```
{
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
            options: {
              // This is the path to your variables
              data: "@import '@/styles/variables.scss'"
            },
            // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
            options: {
              // This is the path to your variables
              prependData: "@import '@/styles/variables.scss'"
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

Inside, `styles` folder, `variables.scss` file keeps variables which needs to be override.

There is a list of variables defined in below link i.e global, component-wise, etc

[Vuetify CSS Variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables#importing-in-variable-files)

Hope this helps!